# U-boot: load kernel via USB

Tags: usb, arm, u-boot, bare-metal

I'm writing a small OS for a ARM board, and I'm a bit tired of the usual "remove SD card, copy kernel, insert SD card, switch on" pattern, so I started to look towards u-boot, and now I'm able to load the kernel via serial port using u-boot and kermit: I don't have to remove/insert the SD card anymore.

However this is painfully slow (~5min for 2.5 Mo), and I wonder if I could do the same using the usb port of the board (I know u-boot support tftpt booting method, but I didn't managed to setup the network correctly so far).

Best,

V.

Comment: If your board's U-boot has the right USB drivers and has USB support compiled in, then yes. Otherwise no. Knowing what board it is would be necessary to determine which. If you do have support, a simple search for "U-boot USB" would tell you everything about how to use it.

Comment: *"do the same using the usb port"* -- That's a vague specification.  Is that a USB host port or a USB device port?  Apparently you are not aware that USB is actually a bus (with data, control and power) to attach peripherals to a host computer.  It is not intended to be just a communications link like RS-232 or a network link like Ethernet.  So there is no conventional method of transferring files over USB.  It can be done, but it's not straight-forward like a serial link.

Comment: Ah, good point - I may have interpreted the question wrong, thinking in terms of straightforward USB mass storage. It does however seem that USB gadget support exists for at least _some_ boards, which may be more in line with what is being asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I indeed don't know much about usb. The board is an Arndale Octa. I guess I should focus on making the Ethernet port working and use the tftp solution.

Comment: 3MB is kinda a lot for a small OS.